# Weird type inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union, union-types

I try to write the type for `payload` based on the current key from the index signature.

The definition works as I expected but when I use it, the type of `payload` is inferred as `never`. I don't know why.

My type definitions:

```
export interface InitCreateServerStateType {
  instanceOptions: InstannceOptionsResponseType | null;
  selectedServerOS: OSDetailType | null;
  selectedServerSpecs: string;
  publicIP: boolean;
  selectedServerFirewall: {} | null;
  sslKeypair: boolean;
  serverName: string;
  numberOfServers: number;
  usePassword: boolean;
  description: string;
  dataSize: number;
}

export type CreateServerStateType = Partial<InitCreateServerStateType>;

export type CreateServerActionType =
    { type: "INIT_INSTANCE_OPTIONS", payload: InstannceOptionsResponseType }
    | { type: "CHANGE_OS", payload: OSDetailType }
    | { type: "CHANGE_SPECS", payload: string }
    | { type: "CHANG_DATA_SIZE", payload: number }
    | { type: "CHANGE_PUBLIC_IP", payload: boolean }
    | { type: "CHANGE_USE_PASSWORD", payload: boolean }
    | { type: "CHANGE_USE_SSL_KEY_PAIR", payload: boolean }
    | { type: "CHANGE_SERVER_NAME", payload: string }
    | { type: "CHANGE_SERVER_NUMBER", payload: number }
```

And when I use it

```
type CreateServerHandlersType = {
  [key in CreateServerActionType['type']]: (state: CreateServerStateType, payload: Extract<CreateServerActionType, { type: key }>['payload']) => CreateServerStateType
}

function reducer(state: CreateServerStateType, action: CreateServerActionType): CreateServerStateType {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  const handlers: CreateServerHandlersType = {
    INIT_INSTANCE_OPTIONS: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, instanceOptions: payload }),
    CHANGE_SPECS: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, selectedServerSpecs: payload }),
    CHANG_DATA_SIZE: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, dataSize: payload }),
    CHANGE_OS: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, selectedServerOS: payload }),
    CHANGE_PUBLIC_IP: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, publicIP: payload }),
    CHANGE_SERVER_NAME: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, serverName: payload }),
    CHANGE_SERVER_NUMBER: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, numberOfServers: payload }),
    CHANGE_USE_PASSWORD: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, usePassword: payload }),
    CHANGE_USE_SSL_KEY_PAIR: (state, payload) => ({ ...state, sslKeypair: payload }),
  };

  const handler = handlers[type];
  return handler ? handler(state, payload) : state;
                     ^ at this point, the type of payload is never  
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: After copying those to TS playground, I found that the local variable `payload` itself is not never, but rather `const payload: string | number | boolean | InstannceOptionsResponseType | OSDetailType`.
But the handler is inferred to be `const handler: (state: Partial<InitCreateServerStateType>, payload: never) => Partial<InitCreateServerStateType>`, which causes the compilation error you saw

Comment: Yes the type of local variable `payload` is what I expect. But I don't know why the `payload` of handler is of type `never`.

Comment: IIRC this has something to do with TS not being very good at use discrimination in values that have been destructured.

Comment: I think it has to do with `|` of multiple function types. A simpler example: a function type like `((arg: A) => void | (arg: B) => void)` is only safe when the argument you pass matches both A and B, so effectively it behaves like `(arg: A&B) => void`. Now if `A&B` is `never`, that means you never have a safe argument to pass. Example in playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwNxVEigCF5MBXAWwCMJVcAoBw6AMQSgApOBDVbAFywAlAgB8UAG4B7dABNRAHy69+Q4qPgSZ84UwA2EYFABmAQgGsGJzgGZRAegcBjHpkzTjtKDyRJ02JgQcgTSUEGSdNacAEQ8MY4ubh5e0L7+gcGh4RCRqFBAA

Comment: @qrsngky has identified the problem correctly. You can work around this by adding a generic type parameter for `reducer`. Consider defining `CreateServerActionType` as a mapping type rather than a union – as it is you can have conflicting payloads for the same `type`. [With a bit of restructuring / renaming you get a working result](https://tsplay.dev/mbEpBN).